# Loading Symbol in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, .net, browser, webbrowser-control

I want to show my client a big circular loading symbol in my web-browser when he is waiting for a page to load. Is it possible with the webbrowser tool present in visual studio? if possible then how? I am working with c#. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks..:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code.

The basic idea is checking the ProgressChanged event of the WebBrowser Control and displaying a PictureBox on the WebBrowser Control.

```
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    public Form6()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pb.Image = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.loading7;
        pb.Visible = false;
        pb.Width = pb.Image.Width;
        pb.Height = pb.Image.Height;
        this.Controls.Add(pb);
    }

    private void webBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CurrentProgress < e.MaximumProgress)
        {
            if (!pb.Visible)
            {
                int x = webBrowser1.Left + ((webBrowser1.Width - pb.Width) / 2);
                int y = webBrowser1.Top + ((webBrowser1.Height - pb.Height) / 2);
                pb.Location = new Point(x, y);
                pb.BringToFront();
                pb.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pb.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ProgressChanged is very unreliable, use DocumentCompleted instead.

Comment: Yes its working. But, how to make it dynamic? I mean, how to make the circle a rotating circle? Do I need to apply multiple images? Any suggestion, guide or tutorial link will be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: See System.Drawing.ImageAnimator